# Most efficient way to copy between S3 accounts

Tags: amazon-s3

I am migrating data from one S3 account (billed to me) to another S3 account (billed to my company).  How do I copy the data in the easiest, fastest, and most cost-effective way?

There are some utilities that do this (like S3 Browser), but they all seem to be Windows-only (no good for me), and I don't really want to buy a piece of software to do a one-time copy operation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can see is to start a server on Amazon EC2, and remote manage a copy tool on this server.

Data traffic between EC2 and S3 is free of charge, and somewhat faster than going over the public internet. I'm pretty sure there is no 'move' command from account to account in S3, so what you're actually doing is downloading the file to your PC, and uploading it again to the new account. This would be done faster & cheaper inside of Amazons datacenters, i.e. from EC2 to S3.

If you don't want to buy software for this, then how about spooling up a Windows or XWindows Linux EC2 instance, and use the [S3Fox Organizer](http://www.s3fox.net/) plugin to Firefox?

If that doesn't work for you, you should be able to script something with one of the [many S3 tools available](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?resultOffset=0&filterEntryTypeID=-1&sortOrder=0&categoryID=188&sortField=107).